# ECR Private endpoint doesn't speed up image pull

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, networking, amazon-ecr, vpc-endpoint

I tried to set up a VPC endpoint for ECR, to speed up my deployments on ECS.
I have 3 endpoints:

- `com.amazonaws.us-east-2.s3`  (`Gateway`)
- `com.amazonaws.us-east-2.ecr.dkr` (`Interface`)
- `com.amazonaws.us-east-2.ecr.api` (`Interface`)

When I pull my images from an EC2 instance in this VPC, here are the pull timers:

- Time of the docker pull without private endpoint: `real   2m15.751s`
- Time of the docker pull with the endpoints: `real 2m12.833s`

Isn't the private endpoint supposed to speed up the docker images pull from my private ECR ?

A dig to the ECR registry shows that it indeed points to the internal network:

```
$ dig XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.amzn2.13.1 <<>> XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 2478
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 10.24.34.215
XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 10.24.41.209
XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 10.24.38.246

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 10.24.0.2#53(10.24.0.2)
;; WHEN: Wed Aug 23 10:06:09 UTC 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 121
```

Is there a reason why the download speed from ECR didn't change ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Did you make sure to remove cached layers before the test?

Comment: Yes, I did a `docker rmi -f` before each test !

Comment: "Isn't the private endpoint supposed to speed up the docker images pull from my private ECR ?" No. The primary purpose of VPC endpoints is security, not performance.